# latex includepdf after section in appendix

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I want to add some pdf-pages in my appendix in latex using this command:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.8,pagecommand={},linktodoc=true]{myPDF.pdf}
```

Works fine so far, however it is always placed in a new page... in other words:

I add `\section{title 1}` and then `\includepdf`-command and then `\section{title 2}` and `\includepdf`-command..... But after each `\section` I get an empty page and then the pdf-files. But I want them to be placed immediately after a section-title, if applicable.

Hope the problem is clear.

Comment: How many pages are in `myPDF.pdf`? Are the page sizes in `myPDF.pdf` and your document the same?

Comment: it's the same size. the page numbers are different.

Comment: If they're the same size, then any regular content you wish to put on the page will be overlaid on top of the included page, so how should that be handled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page

the only thing is to add the \section in the pagecommand of \includepdf like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.8,pagecommand={\section{title 1}\label{}},linktodoc=true]{myPDF1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.8,pagecommand={\section{title 2}\label{}},linktodoc=true]{myPDF2.pdf}
....
```

thanks guys.

UPDATE:
i noticed that \label{} is not working in the pagecommand, hence i cannot reference to any of these appendix-files. is there another workaround?

Answer (score 26):

Another stylish solution in case of adding multi page documents:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=.8,pagecommand={\section{My header}\label{pdf:myfile}},linktodoc=true]{myfile.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,scale=.8,pagecommand={},linktodoc=true]{myfile.pdf}
```

Features:

1. Header placed at the top of the first page without cropping
2. You can set a label for the section created
3. Multi page friendly

Comment: I really like this solution, unfortunately for multi-page pdfs, every page gets its own header and thus clogs up the ToC: 1.1 Appendix A, 1.2 Appendix A, 1.3 Appendix A, etc.

Comment: You need both commands - the first one sets the header on the first page, the second command includes the rest of the pages without the header.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use minipage for this.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}
  \includepdf[pages=1,scale=1,pagecommand={},linktodoc=true]{myPDF.pdf}
\end{minipage}
```